# What does the season pass include?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-2

What does the CoD Black Ops 2 season pass include? Does it unlock all available zombie maps?

Comment: Most season passes grant you access to all the main DLC to a game besides the little bonus ones like gun camos, etc.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [wiki](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Season_Pass) it includes the following map packs and content:

> The Season Pass for Call of Duty: Black Ops II gives access to
>
> - Revolution
> - Uprising
> - Vengeance
> - Apocalypse
>     
>   It also gives access to Nuketown Zombies and an exclusive Calling Card - "The Deuce".

Answer (score 0):

The season pass for Call of Duty Black Ops 2 gives you all four of the released map packs for Call of Duty Black Ops 2, an exclusive in game calling card, and the Nuketown Zombies map. So yes you will get all the zombie maps by purchasing the season pass.